# Cannot get Docker to use pull-through cache

Tags: linux, docker, caching, docker-registry

I am trying to cache images locally in a Docker registry using a pull through cache as described here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/recipes/mirror/. But when I do, Docker seems to ignore the pass-through cache and is instead pulling images directly from Docker Hub.

I have a Docker Compose file that I am using to run the registry:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  registry:
    restart: always
    image: registry:2
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    volumes:
      - ~/.docker/registry:/var/lib/registry
      - ./registry-config.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml
```

And I have configured Docker to use the registry via the `--registry-mirror` option, which I have confirmed is taking effect by checking the output of `docker info`:

```
$ docker info
...
 Registry Mirrors:
  https://localhost:5000/
...
```

But when I try to pull an image, I see no activity in the registry's logs, as if Docker is ignoring the mirror option and just going straight to Docker Hub.

I have also confirmed the registry is working by pulling `alpine:latest` from Docker Hub, tagging it as `localhost:5000/alpine:latest` and pushing it to the registry, then pulling it back out again. Both of which work fine.

This is all being done on a Linux VM running Ubuntu.

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong. and how I am supposed to get Docker to pull all images through the pull-through cache?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The `registry-config.yml` is missing from this question.

Comment: Hi @BMitch. Thanks for the response. I didn't include that because I didn't feel it was relevant to the question. The problem is not with the registry but with the Docker daemon. The daemon is not reaching out to the registry when I try to pull an image.

If the daemon was reaching out, but the image was not being pulled, etc. Then I would have included more info about the registry.